# discord.py no current event loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I have this code which, in theory, will check for how many messages have been sent in a channel, and will do this at a certain time each day. Here is the code:

```
def checkTime():
    # This function runs periodically every 1 second
    threading.Timer(1, checkTime).start()

    now = datetime.now()

    current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    print("Current Time =", current_time)

    if(current_time == '21:35:20'):  # check if matches with the desired time
        print("starting")
        channel = bot.get_channel(this is where I put the channel ID, just hiding it in here)
        counter = 0
        for message in channel.history():
            counter += 1
        print(counter)


checkTime()
```

However, once the time gets to 21:35:20, this error message appears:

```
starting
Exception in thread Thread-9:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jackt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\jackt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 1266, in run
    self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\jackt\Desktop\bot.py", line 51, in checkTime
    for message in channel.history():
  File "C:\Users\jackt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\abc.py", line 1087, in history
    return HistoryIterator(self, limit=limit, before=before, after=after, around=around, oldest_first=oldest_first)
  File "C:\Users\jackt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\iterators.py", line 256, in __init__
    self.messages = asyncio.Queue()
  File "C:\Users\jackt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\queues.py", line 35, in __init__
    self._loop = events.get_event_loop()
  File "C:\Users\jackt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 642, in get_event_loop
    raise RuntimeError('There is no current event loop in thread %r.'
RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-9'.
```

I'm using "from datetime import datetime" and "import threading"

Please can you let me know what my code should look like to prevent this error. Thank you!

Comment: Did you try reading the documentation, in particular trying out the examples, or comparing the approach there to yours? Do you understand what the error message means by "event loop"? What happened when you tried putting `discord.py event loop` [into a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=discord.py+event+loop)? Did you try checking the [official Discord server for discord.py support](https://discord.gg/r3sSKJJ)?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Comment: I would recommend checking out the `discord.py` bot [quickstart tutorial](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html).

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Yes, I have tried as many google searches as I can. However, I can't find the answer to why I keep getting that error, despite googling the error message, looking up everything I can, and yes - reading the documentation. However, I still couldn't find the answer, so I came here for help.

Comment: Why do you think you need threading to accomplish this? Discord.py has a tasks extension for doing background work: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html

Answer (score 0):

In General, with discord.py you should refrain from using threads at all possible as there is almost always an asyncio friendly way to accomplish the task.

As far as the reason for your problem is because `asyncio is single-threaded` the event loop that discord.py runs on is only on 1 thread, so when you try to access the event loop from another thread it will error because it assumes the event loop is on the same thread as you are calling from.

Now given this, asyncio does have threadsafe methods such as [call_soon_threadsafe](http://loop.call_soon_threadsafe)

But for this question specifically, discord.py has an extension **dedicated** to doing periodic tasks in the background: called the tasks extension: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html